# Static class not available in certain other classes

Tags: c#, static

I apologise for this - it's an idiot question and I hate myself for asking it, but I can't figure out a reason for this behaviour.

I have a namespace which contains a mixture of static and non-static classes.

```
namespace MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers
{
    public static class OrderHelper
    { // static methods
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers
{
    public class CountToCampaignConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    { // non-static methods
    }
}
```

These being helper classes, they're used throughout the application. In this class:

```
using MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers;

namespace MyNameSpace.UI.ViewModels
{
    public class QuickCountViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private void BuildOrderExclusionsOnCount()
        {
            CurrentAvailability.OrderExclusions = CountHelper.BuildOrderExclusionAsCsv(ordersToExclude);
        }
    }
}
```

However in this class:

```
using MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers;

namespace MyNameSpace.Service.Services
{
    public class FulfillJobs : BaseService
    { // stuff
    }
}
```

When I try to use my helpler classes, I've got access to the non-static ones, but none of the static ones.

I can't see any naming clash here - if that were the problem, surely I wouldn't be able to get the non-static ones either?

So where else can I look to resolve the issue?

Comment: you can use using MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers.CountToCampaignConverter

Comment: @DhavalPatel No, I can't. If you type in the full namespace like that, the static classes just aren't available at the end of it.

Comment: All the classes are in the same assembly?

Comment: I tried your code and the static class is available. I would assume @ppittle may be correct in his guess?

Comment: @ppittle No, they're not.

Comment: @Beakie Ok, thanks. That tells me there must be something odd in the wider architecture at least. The trouble is I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: Is it Resharper who complains about unavailability or compiler?

Comment: Try renaming FulfillJobs (FulfillJobs2) and drop the BaseService inheritance

Comment: @Dima I don't have resharper. It's the compiler.

Comment: Take the code you posted, put it in a single file and try it. The namespaces are fine.

Comment: @Beakie I'm not doubting you :) But obviously this is just a tiny snapshot of a much bigger system, and the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @MattThrower That is entirely my point. The example given... is fine.

Comment: Are classes from MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers namespace in the same project?

Comment: @Beakie Point taken. I just arbitratily moved the code into another class in a different assembly and it seems to work from there.

Comment: I believe what @Beakie is saying is that we need more context to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Dima Yes. I had no idea that could cause any issues?

Comment: @MattThrower it shouldn't, trying to eliminate missing reference possiblity with this question

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I get that now. But I have no other idea what might cause this issue, so I'm kind of unsure what else I can post. I can't really dump the entire solution into a SO thread :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but no fix was discovered and this issue just happened to me. Here's my particular scenario and the resolution.

I had a Visual Studio 2019 C# solution with two projects: a .NET Standard 2.0 class library and a .NET Core 3.1 console app that used the library. Everything worked fine until I changed the library from .NET Standard 2.0 to 2.1. Afterward, new static items (classes, properties, methods) defined in the library would not be recognized in the app or Visual Studio. If I reset the library back to .NET Standard 2.0 then the static items became visible, but that was not a viable solution for me.

To solve the problem, I set the library's target framework back to .NET Standard 2.1. Then I opened the app project's Reference Manager (Solution Explorer > App Project > Dependencies (right click) > Add Project Reference). I cleared the existing reference to the library and clicked OK. Then I repeated the process, but restored the reference to the library. Suddenly, the app and Visual Studio recognized all the new static items in the library.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because in the second sample, the class is in a different namespaceMyNameSpace.Service.Services.

If you add a "using" for the namespace MyNameSpace.UI.Helpers in your file, it will be visible.

You can also reference your class as UI.OrderHelper from your services, since both share the root "MyNamespace".

Comment: The using statement is already there, as you can see in the sample code.

Comment: Sorry. Any chance that you forgot to reference the DLL with the helpers and there's other DLL that publishes something in the same namespace?

Comment: I don't think so - otherwise I'd face this issue with all the classes within that DLL, and not just some of them, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. None of the classes on that DLL will be accessible.

Comment: Isn't any "typos" in the namespace names. Your problem makes absolutely no sense. If this is reproductible, I can help you. I think there are some information missing.

Comment: Thanks for trying though. Moving this class to a different assembly solves the problem so it's something to do with the wider architecture of the application. Still very puzzling though.

Comment: Check the AssemblyName and Default Namespace in the project options. I never saw something assembly-specific related to this error. The AssemblyName is just how you'll find this assembly through reflecction and the default namespace, which will be the default namespace for new classes. It's nothing very important.